# Python Regex not returning

Tags: python, regex

I have a function that should return a certain number from a mysql table. The number is filtered out of the string using regex like so: `^\((\d*),\)$`. The original string is `(36,)` and the regex should change it to this: `36`. But i still get (36,)!

```
class db:
    con = mysql.connect()
    cur = con.cursor()

def fo(self, query):
    self.cur.execute(query)
    return re.search('^\((\d*),\)$', 
    str(self.cur.fetchone())).group(0)
```

and further on I call the function:

```
return db().fo('SELECT id FROM `GIP-Schema`.user WHERE name = \'{0}\''.format(name))
```

Comment: `.group(0)` -> `.group(1)`

Comment: Capture `group(1)` or change regex to `^\(?:(\d*),\)$`.

Comment: Wow, that easy? Damn...

Comment: `group(0)` is the whole matched expression.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand what you mean, it's the value that the regex is used on, if that wouldn't work, there would be no point in regex, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize that was part of the `return` statement. Wasn't reading carefully enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get Group 1 contents because `^\((\d*),\)$` pattern matches `(` at the start of the string, than *captures into Group 1* zero or more digits (I suggest to capture one or more digits), and then matches `,)` at the end of the string. Also, it is a good idea to first check if a match was found:

```
def fo(self, query):
    self.cur.execute(query)
    m = re.search('^\((\d+),\)$', str(self.cur.fetchone()))
    res = ''
    if m:
        res = m.group(1)
    return res
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uBNPGl/1)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Wiktor for pointing it out, apparently your first group is a 1, not a 0
`.group(0)` -> `.group(1)`